# Using regex to add xml begin and end tags to an xml text via perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm currently trying to modify an existing xml text in a way so that a begin and an end tag are added inside specific tags.
I'm trying to use regex there (in perl), but I'm doing something wrong there.

First as example the original text:

```
......
<xvcs:insert id="1" name="test1" data="mydata"><b>Test1</b></div>
<xvcs:insert id="2" name="test2" class="result">Test2</div>
.....
```

I want to add  after every  tag  and  before every  tag.

Thus it should be:

```
<xvcs:insert id="1" name="test1" data="mydata"><span class="test"><b>Test1</b></span></div>
<xvcs:insert id="2" name="test2" class="result"><span class="test">Test2</span></div>
```

What I got so far is:

```
$newtext =~ s/(\<xvcs\:insert(.)+\>)/$1<span class="test">/g;
$newtext =~ s/(\<\/xvcs\:insert\>)/<\/span>$1/g;
```

But it doesn't function as intended.  The first part adds it even after  which is not as intended.

So my question is there how could it be done better / more stable? (or what did I do wrong there?)

(the result has to be a string which is why I went with the regex path as I don't want to go through an array and combine the arrayelements into a string again one by one).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the string you want to obtain.

Comment: I added it now also as string (didnt think of it as I had described it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
s/(\<xvcs\:insert(.)+\>)/$1<span class="test">/g
```

Cleaned up:

```
s/(<xvcs:insert.+>)/$1<span class="test">/g
```

The problem is that `.+` is too permissive. The following `>` matches the one in "`<b>`". Fixed:

```
s/(<xvcs:insert[^>]*>)/$1<span class="test">/g;
```

All together:

```
$newtext =~ s{(<xvcs:insert[^>]*>)}{$1<span class="test">}g;
$newtext =~ s{(</xvcs:insert>)}{</span>$1}g;
```

Or if you have 5.10+ (for `\K`):

```
$newtext =~ s{<xvcs:insert[^>]*>\K}{<span class="test">}g;
$newtext =~ s{(?=</xvcs:insert>)}{</span>}g;
```